# Reveal.js slide content not showing in Edge Browser

Tags: javascript, reveal.js, microsoft-edge

Using http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/ and found (even with this site) Edge Browser (Windows 10) is not showing some content (some animated text appears during transitions and then disappears.

I have similar behaviour (test example):
http://restacres.com/portfolio/#

Edge has menu option to show in IE... which works.

As of the date of this posting I ensured my Windows Updates were at the latest.

Please compare in Edge vs other Browsers.  I have it working as expected in Chrome, IE 11, Safari, including on numerous phone Browsers (Z10, iphone).

Any suggestions (other than waiting for more updates).  Any one else seeing similar behaviour?

Thanks,

Craig

Comment: Does the console show anything useful?

Comment: At first, yes it did.  There were some improper use of some tags.  I fixed those and now the console is error free, but still echoes the same results--no content on slides. The homepage of reveal.js (http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/ ) echoes the same issue (on some slides).